# How to consider lifecycle in PV power smoothing?

Tags: batteries, solar-energy, cost

I am planning to size Battery for Solar PV system by smoothing the PV output. Capacity size can be obtained by looking at Max charge/discharge needed to smooth the fluctuation.

This should make able to optimize Battery size thus reducing the capital cost. But in the case of annual cost, Battery life should be taken into consideration.

Can someone give a brief explanation on what to consider?

Comment: Handwaving arguments are of little merit without details like local battery cost per watt/hr vs size,  load profile but if you can get economy of scale like in India they can meet or beat cost of coal $40/MWh amortized over 10 yrs

Comment: Tell us more about the system. Is it on grid or off grid? What kind of batteries?

Comment: Sure this was asked a day or so ago.... Ah yes it was in Academia stack. By smoothing, what do you intend - keeping the voltage constant over 24 hours or over hours of daylight?

Comment: It is on grid, output solar PV is fluctuating due to irradiance intermittance. Usually there is ramp limit for the power fluctuation per duration of time. We can use battery to charge/discharge power to make up for the fluctuation. So i am trying to design suitable battery size for this purpose.

Comment: Charging capacity is equal Net PV power minus smoothed power, and vise versa for discharging. So basically, minimum battery capacity would be the difference of net PV power and smoothed power. Method for smoothing in moving average. That is for sizing battery, but I am wondering if smoothing process have any effect on battery lifetime.

Comment: I never understood why anyone would be interested in  grid-tied PV.  If you are connected to the grid then why have solar?  The cost of the batteries vs. the cost of a kW from the grid, makes it uneconomical.  Regardless of how much the stress is reduced on the batteries, it's not going to be a sustainable system without subsidies.  Look at the research done by Sandia National Laboratories.

Comment: From a cost perspective, there is no point in adding batteries to a typical grid-tie system. But I think the simplest thing would be to size the batteries so that they can supply about 15 to 18 hours of your average power consumption. That should smooth out most daily variations. You will still go into deficit during long periods without sun. But it is really unclear what you are actually trying to do, and why.

Comment: @Misunderstood, where I live, in California, grid tie is financially advantageous, especially if you can install yourself. Even if you just call a solar contractor and write a check, you will break even in probably 10 years, which is arguably still a good investment. But if you add batteries to the system, then you will literally never break even. You might as well just burn the money. Batteries only make sense if you don't have a grid-tie option, or if you attach value to non-monetary benefits from being grid independent.

Comment: @mkeith In Florida I now pay less than 10¢ a kW.  PV panels cost me about $1.20/W.  I have four 100W panels and four SLA 7 Ah batteries @ ≈ $8 ea.  I use a MorningStar 30 A TriStar MPPT,  I use a Mean Well 48 V supply and a Linear Tech  Ideal Diode LTC4355CDE eval board to switch from PV to Mean Well when PV output fell below 48V.  The TriStar is the weak link.  It appears to only have a buck driver with no boost and it draws too much power from the batteries overnight with no low battery cutoff.  MorningStar tech support said my batteries capacity was too low.  I was close and gave it up.

Comment: I am paying (depending on tier) over 20c per kWh. Batteries still don't break even for me. I have room for ground mount, so I have about 5.2kW of solar. I payed about $1400 for all the modules (they are older shell solar modules being sold by people doing upgrades). Some more for racking and wiring. Inverter was here when I moved in, so that is kind of rolled in to home cost. I should break even in a few years. It is saving me at least a thousand dollars per year. My total energy useage is around 30kWh per day. Solar supplies 20kWh. So my net use age is 10kWh/day.